# How to get include? to work with my code

Tags: ruby, methods, include

I'm trying to update a movie list called `movies`. I want to use `include?` to figure out whether a program is trying to update a movie already on the list or if the movie is not currently included in `movies`.

Here's the object movies

```
movies = {
:"Mean Girls" => 4,
Avatar: 2,
:"Spiderman 2" => 3,
Shrek: 4
}
```

The update is under a case statement.

```
  when "update"
  puts "Type in the movie you'd like to update"
  title = gets.chomp
  if movies[title.to_sym].include?(title.to_sym)
    puts "Type in a new rating of 1-4 for that movie"
    rating = gets.chomp
    movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
  else
    puts "That movie is not currently in our movie list"
  end
```

When I type in the title of the movie I want to update I get the error message:

```
undefined method `include?' for 4:Fixnum
```

What does that mean? Is it not possible to use the `include?` method here?

I also tried removing `title.to_sym` after `include?` but that didn't work either.

Here's all my code

```
    movies = {
    :"Mean Girls" => 4,
    Avatar: 2,
    :"Spiderman 2" => 3,
    Shrek: 4
}

puts "Do you want to add a movie, update a movie ranking, display all movies and rankings or delete a movie?"
choice = gets.chomp

case choice

when "add"
    puts "Type in the movie you'd like to add"
    title = gets.chomp.to_sym
    if movies[title].nil?
        puts "Type in a rating of 1-4 for that movie"
        rating = gets.chomp.to_i
        movies[title] = rating
    else
        puts "That movie is already in our list. Run the program and select update to change its rating"
    end
when "update"
    puts "Type in the movie you'd like to update"
    title = gets.chomp
    if movies[title.to_sym].include?(title.to_sym)
        puts "Type in a new rating of 1-4 for that movie"
        rating = gets.chomp
        movies[title.to_sym] = rating.to_i
    else
        puts "That movie is not currently in our movie list"
    end
when "display" 
    puts "Movies!"
when "delete"
    puts "Deleted!"
else
    puts "Error!"
end
```

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We can't tell what `movies` contains but it looks like it's supposed to be a hash of arrays and you want to see if `title.to_sym` is in it. But that's just guessing because your code doesn't run nor does it demonstrate the problem.

Comment: The error means that you're trying to apply the `include?` method on a `Fixnum` (likely an integer). `movies[title.to_sym]` is evidently just a number and it doesn't accept the `include?` method.

Comment: It looks like **movies[title.to_sym]** is a Fixnum, and a Fixnum has no method include?... But, as @theTinMan pointed above, your code does not help too much when it comes to know what is happening. Please, show more code.

Comment: I've added the movies object  to my code now @theTinMan

Comment: added code @EddeAlmeida

Comment: Use of symbols for the titles is probably not a good idea.  When dealing with potentially large numbers of values, symbols are not a good choice because they are never removed from the Ruby runtime, whereas strings can be garbage collected when they fall out of scope.

Comment: @KeithBennett I'm new to programming. Can you elaborate on this a little more? I get that you're saying something along the lines of symbols are always using memory, while strings don't but I'm not clear when exactly its better to use strings vs symbols.

Comment: @Gwater17 It's a nontrivial issue and much has been written about it.  I suggest googling "ruby symbols vs strings".  My point about memory was that in Ruby, when strings are no longer used, they may be removed from memory.  As I understand it, that is not true for symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since movies is a hash containing the movie titles as keys, with whatever numbers you've specified as values, that is why

```
movies[title.to_sym]
```

gives you the Fixnum 4, and Fixnum does not have an "include?" method.

You mean to say

```
movies.include?(title.to_sym)
```

which will return true/false if your hash has that title as a key.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem:

```
movies = {
  :"Mean Girls" => 4,
  Avatar: 2,
  :"Spiderman 2" => 3,
  Shrek: 4
}

movies['Avatar'.to_sym]  # => 2
movies['Avatar'.to_sym].include?('Avatar'.to_sym)  # => 

# ~> NoMethodError
# ~> undefined method `include?' for 2:Fixnum
```

If you want to see if a particular title is a key in your hash you can do it like this:

```
title = 'Avatar'
movies.key?(title.to_sym) # => true

title = 'Blade Runner'
movies.key?(title.to_sym) # => false
```

Knowing that you can a sensible conditional test using something like:

```
if movies.key?(title.to_sym)
```

If you're always going to have integers for the values, and never `false` or `nil`, then you could shorten it to:

```
if movies[title.to_sym]
```

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to test if a title is a key in my hash. When I changed .include? to .key? I still got the same error message `include_method_test.rb:26:in `<main>': undefined method `key?'` for 4:Fixnum (NoMethodError)  Any idea why?

Comment: Whoops, yeah I didn't!